# drawing flickers

Tags: c#, drawing

have made something to draw on the screen(as overlay for everyting else) but when I move something over the drawing it starts flickering, I have already set DoubleBuffered on true
is their a way to fix this with a dll,function,rendering?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoubleBuffered = true;
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();        
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Point midx = new Point(960, 960);
    Point midy = new Point(540, 540);

    Point LinksBoven = new Point(10, 10);
    Point pt = Cursor.Position;
    string letter = "drawing on";
    float emSize = 12;

   while (true)
   {
       using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
       {                              
           System.Drawing.Pen myPen;
           myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 200, 0));
           g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

           if (cbCircel.Checked == true)
           {
               g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, midx.X - 10, midy.Y - 10, 20, 20);
           }

           if (cbKruis.Checked == true)
           {                                       
               g.DrawLine(myPen, 940, 540, 980, 540);
               g.DrawLine(myPen, 960, 560, 960, 520);    
           }

           pt.X = 10;
           pt.Y = 10;

           g.DrawString(letter, new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, emSize, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(Color.Green), pt);            
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You may have made the form double buffered but you completely override that with calls to draw lines (etc), you probably need to draw all your lines to a separate image first then swap them out. This will reduce the issue at least

Comment: Perhaps a silly assumption... Could it be that the async task has not been completed while you're moving the cursor?

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize that, but your code is drawing on the desktop window, not your form.